# Configuring Monit to monitor Rocketjob

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, rvm, monit

This is what I have currently in monitrc file:

```
check process rocketjob
        matching "rocketjob"
        start program = "bin/bash -c 'source $HOME/.rvm/bin/rvm cd /home/ghias/projects/my_project/ && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rocketjob --quiet >> log/rocketjob.log'"
```

and it gives me this error in monit log file:

```
'rocketjob' failed to start (exit status 1) -- bin/bash: bin/bash: /.rvm/bin/rvm: No such file or directory
```

whereis rvm command gives me `rvm: /home/user/.rvm/bin/rvm`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There are some things in your command:

1. Try using absolute paths for the initial binary. So `/bin/bash` with leading `/`
2. You try to source `$HOME/.rvm/bin/rvm` with arguments `cd` and `/home/ghias/projects/my_project/`. I think there should be a `;` or `&&` right before `cd`

You might also want to consider an executable with those commands. It is way easier to implement, read, and debug:

**Contents of `/root/monit_do_rocketjob`:**

```
#!/bin/bash

source $HOME/.rvm/bin/rvm
cd /home/ghias/projects/my_project/

export RAILS_ENV=production
bundle exec rocketjob --quiet >> log/rocketjob.log

exit $?
```

Don't forget to make this executable.

**Monit config:**

```
check process rocketjob
        matching "rocketjob"
        start program = "/root/monit_do_rocketjob"
```